# future take a long time to run, why not return immediately?

Tags: scala, future

I have the following code,and I expected a.success(burncpu(14969)) to return instantly since it's run in a future, but why it took a long time to run.

```
import scala.concurrent._
val a=Promise[Unit]()
// why the following took long time here, shouldn't it be in async mode, and return very quick
a.success(burncpu(14969))  
a.future


def burncpu(a:Int):Int = {
  val point=new Date().getTime()
  while ((new Date()).getTime()-point< a) {
    a
  }
  a
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `Promise` wrong.

`a.success` method completes the promise with given argument, it doesn't run the expression you pass to it asynchronously.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
val f = Future(burncpu(6000))
```

Assuming you have an `ExecutionContext` available (if you don't, you can do `import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`), this will construct a [`Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) which will run your function asynchronously.

You can see how it works in Scala REPL (`f.value` returns `None` until the method has returned)

```
scala> val f = Future(burncpu(6000))
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4d4d8fcf

scala> f.value
res27: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = None

scala> f.value
res28: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = None

scala> f.value
res29: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Success(6000))
```

Answer (score 3):

`Promise.success` is not executed asynchronously, basically your code is the equivalent of:

```
Future.successful(burncpu(14969))
```

You could try this:

```
Future {
  burncpu(14969)
}
```

This will call `Future.apply` and execute your function asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `future` is indeed called asynchronously. **However, nothing in the API suggests that completing the `Promise`, i.e. calling `success` in your case, will be executed asynchronously. That is your responsibility to ensure.**

It makes sense when you consider **what a [`Promise`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise) is - a "marker" to another execution path, notifying it that a calculation has been completed and a result (or failure) is available.**